# How can I abstract this repeating pattern in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

In my templates I've got these repeating blocks of content which I want to abstract to a single component:

```html
<header class="Component-header">
  <!-- Some content here is always the same -->
  <!-- And some content is different for each use -->
</header>
<div class="Component-body">
  <!-- Some content here is always the same -->
  <!-- And some content is different for each use -->
</div>
<footer class="Component-footer">
  <!-- Some content here is always the same -->
  <!-- And some content is different for each use -->
</footer>
```

Normally I would use a razor partial view for this, and pass it some variables. However in this case that would mean passing big chunks of html as variables, which doesn't seem wise.

I've found this article: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/09/custom-helper-for-surrounding-block-in.html, which explains how to create block helpers. It's a little closer to what I'm trying to do, but it still requires me to define the html as a string, which is not what I want (as the amount of html is sizeable enough for it to become unmaintainable).

From what I understand I can't use layouts for this either, because the components occur multiple times on one page. So my question is: how can I abstract the pattern above to a single reusable component, which I can reuse on a page, which accepts multiple areas of html and accepts variables?

Comment: Functionally what I want resembles the way emberjs handles components: https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/components/wrapping-content-in-a-component/, but what I want would have multiple `yield` areas.

Comment: You could also look up front end frameworks which abstract this problem away from you, so you only have to deal with the proper view logic. Frameworks such as Aurelia, ReactJs, AngularJS 1/2

Comment: @CallumLinington You mean for use in combination with .net mvc?

Comment: No you would find it better to use in conjunction with WebApi - which isn't a difficult move at all from MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what works for me is using a razor `@helper`. The code below goes in your `App_Code`, where you create the file `YourComponentName.cshtml`. In that file use the following markup:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@helper Render(
  ViewContext context,
  string title = "Default title",
  Func<object, object> header = null,
  Func<object, object> content = null,
  Func<object, object> footer = null
)
{
  <header class="Component-header">
    <!-- Some content here is always the same -->
    <h3>@title</h3>
    @if (header != null) { @header.DynamicInvoke(context); }
  </header>
  <div class="Component-content">
    <!-- Some content here is always the same -->
    @if (content != null) { @content.DynamicInvoke(context); }
  </div>
  <footer class="Component-footer">
    <!-- Some content here is always the same -->
    @if (footer != null) { @footer.DynamicInvoke(context); }
  </footer>
}
```

Then you can use the component in your templates with:

```
  @YourComponentName.Render(
    ViewContext,
    title: "Title",
    header: @<p>Markup for the header</p>,
    content: @<p>The content</p>,
    footer: @<p>Markup for the footer</p>
  )
```